# What happened to question I flagged

Tags: support, flagging

I have recently flagged the [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16280/battery-acid-density-of-1-285-grams-per-cubic-centimeter), which was helpful. So i thought the question will be delete. But it still there.

So what is rules for that?

Comment: "helpful" means "Please continue to flag such things", but it might not necessarily mean that action was taken in the particular case :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cross-posting *is* highly discouraged, so thank you for bringing it to our attention.

If the question were more appropriate for Math.SE, I would have closed our version.  I think it's most appropriate on Chem, so I let it stand.  I did not follow up with Math.SE to see if their version was closed.

The flag was helpful, so it was marked as such.  Flagging doesn't guarantee that there will be any action taken by the moderators.